# Getting NA returned on postResample Prediction

Tags: r, r-caret

Getting this result when trying to test predictive accuracy of logistic regression model. It doesn't seem right. Any help appreciated!

```
> dput(head(test$subscribed))
structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("no", "yes"), class = 
"factor")
```

Input

```
predictions <- predict(final_model, test, type = "response")`
class_pred<- as.factor(ifelse(predictions > .5, "Yes", "No"))
postResample(class_pred, test$subscribed)
```

Output

```
 Accuracy    Kappa 
  NA       NA
```

Comment: can you check if there is any NAs in class_pred. ```table(is.na(class_pred))```. you need to remove the NAs

Comment: Hi, this is the output of that. FALSE 
 6907

Comment: I cannot reproduce your error. if you just need accuracy, do ```confusionMatric(table(class_pred, test$subscribed))```

Comment: what actually is ```final_model```, is it fitted using glm, as you can see, your question is lacking a lot of information. see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: It's confusing me this one, yes it's just for accuracy- I get this error for the confusion matrix        Error in confusionMatrix.table(table(class_pred, test$subscribed)) : 
  the table must the same classes in the same order

Comment: Yes final_model is a logistic regression model, independent variables used to predict binomial yes/no repsonse

Comment: yeah sure, thats done

Comment: you did not set the levels correctly. See my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's say your data is like this:

```
df = data.frame(subscribed=sample(c("yes","no"),100,replace=TRUE),
x1 = runif(100),x2=runif(100))
```

Set the factor correctly:

```
df$subscribed = factor(df$subscribed,levels=c("no","yes"))
```

Do the model:

```
traindf = df[1:70,]
test = df[1:30,]
final_model = glm(subscribed ~ .,data=traindf,family="binomial")
```

And predict, and set the factors with the same levels, note the levels are case sensitive, using `"yes"` is different from `"Yes"` :

```
predictions <- predict(final_model, test, type = "response")
class_pred<- ifelse(predictions > .5, "yes", "no")
class_pred = factor(class_pred,levels=c("no","yes"))
```

Then:

```
confusionMatrix(table(class_pred, test$subscribed))
Confusion Matrix and Statistics

          
class_pred no yes
       no   0   1
       yes 14  15
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This solved the issue, I tried to upvote but not at the required rep level yet. Thanks again!

Comment: no problem. you can accept the answer i think